# How to get parameter names via reflection in kotlin?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

java8 has "-parameters" argument, passed to compiler, what about kotlin ? 
As I can see, kotlin compiler add @JetValueParameter annotation with param names  to parameters, but one is depricated..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**: *Reflection API now supports obtaining parameter names: `KCallable.parameters` will give you a list of parameters, and `KParameter.name` will give you the name.*

The current solution is to use the `JetValueParameter` annotation, although it is deprecated.

We're working on support for the parameter names in Kotlin reflection, which will be available shortly. At that point `JetValueParameter` will be dropped in favor of the new API.

I'd like to note that Kotlin compiler currently only produces JVM bytecode compatible with Java 1.6, whereas the `MethodParameters` attribute corresponding to the `-parameters` of javac only appeared in bytecode of Java 1.8. So, you'll still be unable to get parameter names of Kotlin methods via *Java reflection*. We're considering the support for bytecode target 1.8 though, so that will likely work in the future.

Comment: Alexander, is it still the same or has anything updated since (i.e. any chance for Java to be able to see Kotlin parameter names)?

Comment: @YuriiRashkovskii We're adding support for target bytecode version 1.8 currently, but writing the `MethodParameters` attribute is not planned yet. Please create an issue in our tracker, if this would be useful to you!

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov what is the update on this? Any link with documentation?