# Kotlin: How to specify a named arguent with a variable?

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have two methods:

```
    private fun method1(a: A): A {
        return a.copy(v1 = null)
    }

    private fun method2(a: A): A {
        return a.copy(v2 = null)
    }
```

Can I write something like:

```
    private fun commonMethod(a: A, variableToChange: String): A {
        return a.copy($variableToChange = null)
    }
```

Another words, can I use a variable to refer to a named argument?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this without using reflection

Comment: I don't either...

Comment: you can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425846/how-to-get-parameter-names-via-reflection-in-kotlin

Comment: @Daniel thanks, I suppose it's the closest possibility to use reflection.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to archive I would recommend to pass a setter to the method e.g.

```
fun <A>  changer (a: A, setter: (a: A) -> Unit ) {
    // do stuff
    setter(a)
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Assuming the intention was to make an exact copy and then change one field with respect to the original, this could work just fine.  The wrapper method would then hide the setter unit logic.

Comment: Yes, It is what I want to do, but the problem is that the variable which I want to change can be val. Therefore the only chance is to copy the object replacing the variable with the named argument.

Comment: You can make the "setter" function return a value of type A, it will just lead to repeating the `copy` code, which I guess was what you wanted to avoid. Basically, using this answer leads to more code than the initial unrolled version of the OP :'(

Comment: Yes, it might work, but I'm afraid I want to avoid huge refactoring. If I change the signature of the variable, it may provoke many questions from my colleagues)

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution for this problem (with usage of reflection) is:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> copyValues(a: T, values: Map<String, Any?>): T {
    val function = a::class.functions.first { it.name == "copy" }
    val parameters = function.parameters

    return function.callBy(
        values.map { (parameterName, value) ->
            parameters.first { it.name == parameterName } to value
        }.toMap() + (parameters.first() to a)
    ) as T
}
```

This works with all data classes and all classes that have a custom copy function with the same semantics (as long as the parameter names are not erased while compiling). In the first step the function reference of the copy method is searched ([`KFunction<*>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-function/index.html)). This object has two importent properties. The [`parameters`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/parameters.html) property and the [`callBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/call-by.html) function.

With the `callBy` function you can execute all function references with a map for the parameters. This map must contain a reference to the receiver object.

The `parameters` propery contains a collection of `KProperty`. They are needed as keys for the `callBy` map. The name can be used to find the right `KProperty`. If a function as a parameter that is not given in the map it uses the default value if available or throws an exception.

Be aware that this solution requires the full reflection library and therefore only works with Kotlin-JVM. It also ignores typechecking for the parameters and can easily lead to runtime exceptions.

You can use it like:

```
data class Person (
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val foo: Boolean
)

fun main() {
    var p = Person("Bob", 18, false)

    println(p)
    p = copyValues(p, mapOf(
        "name" to "Max",
        "age" to 35,
        "foo" to true
    ))
    println(p)
}

// Person(name=Name, age=15, foo=false)
// Person(name=Max, age=35, foo=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using reflection:

```
val param = it::copy::parameters.findParameterByName(variableToChange)!!
a::copy.callBy(mapOf(param to null)
```

When you will call the method you can specify parameter names in a strongly typed manner because you use the copy method, like this: `A::property.name`